# Can't see image and contents page in webview android on real Device

Tags: android, webview

I have writing one app with WebView. My problem is the page can't load in real device. When I had run on an emulator, that page can see all images and contents. My code is looked like below.

My Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;
private static final String TAG = "TaoBao";
//private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FloatingActionMenu materialDesignFAM;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton1, floatingActionButton2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    // webview
     myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_webview);
    final WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    //webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    //webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // set javascript and zoom and some other settings
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    // enable all plugins (flash)
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);



    // Floating Menu
    materialDesignFAM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.material_design_android_floating_action_menu);
    floatingActionButton1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.material_design_floating_action_menu_item1);
    floatingActionButton2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.material_design_floating_action_menu_item2);


    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final ACProgressFlower progressDialog = new ACProgressFlower.Builder(this)
            .direction(ACProgressConstant.DIRECT_CLOCKWISE)
            .themeColor(Color.WHITE)
            .text("Loading...")
            .fadeColor(Color.DKGRAY).build();
    progressDialog.show();

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
           // if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
            //    return false;
           // }
           // if (appInstalledOrNot(url)) {
           //     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
           //     startActivity( intent );
            //} else {
                // do something if app is not installed
           // }
          //  return true;

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;

        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TaoBao.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });

    myWebView.loadUrl("https://m.intl.taobao.com/");

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}enter code here
```

main_activity.xml

```
`       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/activity_webview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>`
```

`Here is My Screenshot

Test on Real Device Android 4.3
[image]

Test on Emulator Android 4.3 
[image]

On real device can not see any photo and contents from the web. But on emulator can see image and content. How to fix it can see image and content on real device? Please help me. 
Best Regards,
STP

Comment: do you included internet permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes, I had add internet permission in manifest.xml. Here it's. '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--permission for internet-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>'

Comment: use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews. Check the network tab if there is any error while fetching images or not.